# INSERT INTO postgres not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hate asking about little stupid bugs like this, but I can't figure it out for the life of me...

This query:

```
INSERT INTO user_authentication(init_password_setup) VALUES( substr((md5(random()::TEXT)), 0, 10) ) WHERE (init_password_setup = NULL OR init_password_setup ='')
```

Is throwing this error:

```
 16:27:11 Kernel error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

I tried running it as an insert select as well. Sincere thanks for any help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: sorry, guys. very dumb. not sure what I was thinking. late in the day. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 4):

INSERT statement doesn't have WHERE clause. But you can use INSERT ... SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO user_authentication (user_id, init_password_setup) 
    SELECT id, substr((md5(random()::TEXT)), 0, 10)
    FROM users 
    WHERE <some condition here>;
```

or just update existed records:

```
UPDATE user_authentication
SET init_password_setup = substr((md5(random()::TEXT)), 0, 10)
WHERE init_password_setup IS NULL OR init_password_setup ='';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify an already existing row, you need an `UPDATE` statement not an `INSERT` statement.

Update will modify the existing row(s), Insert will add a new row in the table.

```
UPDATE user_authentication
  SET init_password_setup = substr((md5(random()::TEXT)), 0, 10)
WHERE init_password_setup IS NULL 
   OR init_password_setup =''
```

Answer (score 1):

An `insert` statement has no `where` clause. Either insert new data or update existing data with the `update` clause (which can have a `where` clause).

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ` is perfectly valid. The problem is that you cannot use a `WHERE` clause in a `VALUES` set-expression. That said, I agree that the user appears confused and seems to be trying to use `INSERT` to `UPDATE` a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do INSERT with a WHERE clause.
If you are trying to INSERT, then just use VALUES.
If you want to use where then use UPDATE.

Comment: This is mistaken for the same reasons as @jurgend's answer